# How to load google fonts and material icons inside vue 3 custom web components

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, web-component

so I'm creating custom web components using Vue 3 to be used in any web application and I'm running into a problem when it comes to importing fonts and Google material icons because of the shadow-root. My current approach is to add the stylesheet link tag to the application header when the web components are registered, it works however I feel like it defeats the encapsulating idea of web components and I feel like this can affect the styles of the application that is using my custom web components.

Here is my current implementation.

```
import { defineCustomElement as VueDefineCustomElement, h, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

export function register() {
  // Icons
  loadStylesheet(
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200'
  );
  // Fonts
  loadStylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

  // components
  customElements.define('comp', defineCustomElement(comp1));

  ...
}

export const defineCustomElement = (component) => {
  ...

  return VueDefineCustomElement({
    setup() {
      ... // some data injection
      return () => h(component);
    },
  });
};

// Function to add the stylesheets to applications head tag
function loadStylesheet(href) {
  let existingNode = null; // get existing stylesheet node if it already exists:
  for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href && document.styleSheets[i].href.indexOf(href) > -1) {
      existingNode = document.styleSheets[i].ownerNode;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (existingNode) {
    return;
  } // already exists so don't need to add again

  let linkTag = document.createElement('link');
  linkTag.rel = 'stylesheet';
  linkTag.href = href;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkTag);
}
```

And in the root component I did the following

```
@import url('../index.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200');
:host {
  font-family: Lato, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I have thought about download the font and using that and replacing icons with svg. However I feel like this will increase the bundle size.

Comment: This how fonts work, they are loaded in the main document

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman What if the main application uses the same font, will it not affect them? this is why I want to have font only for my web components so it does not affect the application outside of it.

Comment: When your component connects, check if the font already exists, if not load it

Comment: "I feel like this can affect the styles of the application that is using my custom web components." It shouldn't; they just make the fonts available. Anything else not using that font family won't be impacted; anything already using that font family won't either. Nothing changes.

Answer (score -3):

To add icons, go to font awesome sign UP and get your embedded kit code.

Insert it in the HTML header part. Then you can search in the website for icons it is easy to insert them

Comment: This is not the solution I was looking for because custom web elements don't have an index.html or header of their own. I do not want to add a link tag to the parent applications header that uses my web components